# How do I create a thumbnail from a video using copyCGImageAtTime in Swift?

Tags: swift, thumbnails

I'm trying to create a thumbnail from a video using `copyCGImageAtTime`, but I keep on getting the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value.

I've used a break on the line after calling `copyCGImageAtTime` and discovered that `img` is `nil`. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
 func generateThumbnail() -> UIImage
 {
        var fileArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathsForResourcesOfType    (".mp4", inDirectory: "")
        var moviePath : String = fileArray[1] as! String
        let url = NSURL(string: moviePath)
        var asset : AVAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(url) as! AVAsset
        var assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        var durationSeconds: Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)
        var time: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds/2.0, 600)
        var actualTime: UnsafeMutablePointer<CMTime> = nil
        var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
        var img: CGImage! = assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: actualTime, error: error)
        var frameImg : UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: img)!
        return frameImg
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. However, I got the information from this method. Maybe you can adapt it to your code.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
let tempImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
let pathString = tempImage.relativePath

var url:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathString!)!
var asset:AVAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(url) as! AVAsset
var assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
var time: CMTime = asset.duration
    time.value = 0

var imageRef: CGImage! = assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil, error: nil)

var frameImg : UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)!

return framImg
}
```